# Limits with cubic root without L’Hopital’s Rule: $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}-1}{x-1} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, radicals, limits-without-lhopital

I need to solve

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}-1}{x-1} $$

But without using L’Hopital’s Rule, could someone help me?

Answer (score 6):

Factorize $x-1$ as $$\left(\sqrt[3]{x}-1\right)\left(x^{2/3}+x^{1/3}+1\right)$$

Comment: Alright where do I go from there?

Comment: @GeorgeG your limit becomes $$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}-1}{\left(\sqrt[3]{x}-1\right)\left(x^{2/3}+x^{1/3}+1\right)}$$

Comment: Cancel the factor of $\sqrt[3]{x}-1$

Answer (score 1):

Taking $f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x}$ your expression becomes
$$ \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{f(x) - f(1)}{x - 1} = f'(1).$$

Comment: How do you evaluate $f'(1)$ if you cannot evaluate this limit?

Comment: I was under the impression that the derivative of $x \mapsto x^{1/3}$ is known.

Comment: No it isn't. You either need to use this, or find the derivative using thegeneralized binomial expansion, (which happens to be the general proof for the derivative of $x\mapsto x^n$). This is the same as factoring, and needs to be shown explicitly.

Comment: Yeah, we need to know the derivative of $x \mapsto x^3$ then we can use the chain rule on $f(x)^3 = x$ to get the derivative of $f$. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Mathias, your procedure works, but a simpler way would be to use $(1+x)^n = 1+nx+\frac{n(n-1)x^2}{2}+\cdots$ in the limit definition of the derivative.

Comment: The instructions were to find the limit without L'Hopital. @MatthiasKlupsch did that perfectly, and this is the simplest solution.