# Calculating $\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\sqrt[3]{x}-1}{x-1}$ without L´Hôpital rule.

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

How to calculate the limit above without using L´Hôpital rule? I am not able to factor the numerator and I´ve also tried factoring the numerator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limits with cubic root without L’Hopital’s Rule: $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}-1}{x-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736563/limits-with-cubic-root-without-l-hopital-s-rule-lim-x-to-1-frac-sqrt3x)

Comment: $x-1=(\sqrt[3]{x}-1)(\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x}+1)$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

$$a^{3} - b^{3} = (a-b)(a^{2} + ab + b^{2})$$

Answer (score 0):

Nothing new, but little modification to previous answers for your easier understanding.  Put $\sqrt[3]{x}=y.$ Then your problem is
$$\lim_{y\rightarrow 1}\frac{y-1}{y^3-1}= \lim_{y\rightarrow 1}\frac{y-1}{(y-1)(y^2+y+1)}=\frac{1}{3}.$$